# How might I implement tab completion in GoLang?

Tags: go, tab-completion

I have an interactive program written in Go.

How might I go about implementing tab completion within the program?

Would command history be possible (pressing up/down arrow key)?

Example:

`$ ./go-program`

`(Go-Program)> set option <tab tab>`

Comment: This sounds pretty broad. You might look into using readline functionality, for example through [this implementation](https://github.com/chzyer/readline).

Comment: have a look at this: https://github.com/abiosoft/ishell

Comment: You could wrap the Bash Complete command like here: https://github.com/rwxrob/bonzai/blob/7f457a1b75612018e6e35f21ac73c10caf9c9f49/z/cmd.go .. read more about Complete here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1444201/795299